# Downloading files with HTTP via Ruby: file cannot be opened, may be damaged

Tags: ruby, http, file-io, download

I am using this snippet of code:

```
puts u.host + "/" + u.path
resp = http.get(u.host + "/" + u.path)
File.open(filename, "w") do |file|
    file.write resp.body
end
```

If I just type the result from `puts u.host + "/" + u.path` in the browser, I can clearly see the file. However, the file that downloads can't be opened because it's "damaged". What is the reason for this? Is it because it's from an HTTPS server? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Use `wb` if it's a binary file

Comment: I'm planning on using this for just about any kind of file type (It takes user input for the file types to scrape). I'm currently testing for pdf files, and both "w" and "wb" had the same result mentioned in the original post

Comment: Whether the file is text or binary, use `"wb"` to save it if you want the file to be stored in the same format it was received.

Comment: Yes.  You really need to be checking your error codes.  This code on its own will not download a file frmo an https server -- in fact it won't even do the ssl handshake to even make an http request.

Comment: What is telling you that the file is damaged?  Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: Okay, using `"wb"` now. Here is the error:  
  
`The file “test%202013.pdf” could not be opened. It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.`

Comment: Upon inspecting the file in a text editor, it contains `"Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand."` So it is a result of a bad request. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by changing my get code following this format:
http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2011/09/27/large-ruby-file-downloads-done-right/